# Using group_by to check for a cell value, then, if it exists, adding it to all column cells in the group

Tags: r, filter, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to perform a fairly complex dplyr function.

I have a dataset of rows and columns of FEC. It looks like this:

```
    cov_end_dat tot_rec idfull       rep_typ                            

1   3/31/07 271972.12   H6WI070332008   Q1
2   6/30/07 303687.1    H6WI070332008   Q2
3   9/30/07 158947.03   H6WI070332008   Q3
4   12/31/07    174545.28   H6WI070332008   YE
5   3/31/08 267260.1    H6WI070332008   Q1
6   6/30/08 280075.62   H6WI070332008   Q2
7   8/20/08 58659.79    H6WI070332008   12P
8   9/30/08 114268.7    H6WI070332008   Q3
9   10/15/08    38125   H6WI070332008   12G
10  11/24/08    78178.97    H6WI070332008   30G
11  12/31/08    3448.67 H6WI070332008   YE
```

There's an ID for every candidate and a "rep_type" (report type).

I'm trying to perform the following operation. For every candidate (all have the same IDFULL value), I want to look to see if there's a Q1 value. If there is, I want to take value of the cov_end cell in that row and assign it to all cells with the same IDFULL in a new column called "Q1date". Otherwise, I want to assign a preset date to it.

The way I've tried to do this is something like:

```
data %>% group_by(idfull) %>% %>% mutate(Q1date = SOMEHOW LOOK INSIDE GROUP FOR VALUE?) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: you could pull out all the cov_end values for the Q1s and then just left_join them back to your data leaving out the rep_type.

Comment: @Puddlebunk That makes sense!

Comment: In your example you have two rows with `Q1` for the same `idfull`.  Which of the two different values of `cov_end` do you want to fill your new column with?

Comment: The earlier one.. There's another column called elec_year. It's for elec_year minus 1. @AndrewGustar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do

```
data %>% group_by(idfull) %>% 
     mutate(Q1date=first(cov_end_dat[rep_typ=="Q1"]))

   cov_end_dat tot_rec idfull        rep_typ Q1date 
   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>         <chr>   <chr>  
 1 3/31/07     271972. H6WI070332008 Q1      3/31/07
 2 6/30/07     303687. H6WI070332008 Q2      3/31/07
 3 9/30/07     158947. H6WI070332008 Q3      3/31/07
 4 12/31/07    174545. H6WI070332008 YE      3/31/07
 5 3/31/08     267260. H6WI070332008 Q1      3/31/07
 6 6/30/08     280076. H6WI070332008 Q2      3/31/07
 7 8/20/08      58660. H6WI070332008 12P     3/31/07
 8 9/30/08     114269. H6WI070332008 Q3      3/31/07
 9 10/15/08     38125. H6WI070332008 12G     3/31/07
10 11/24/08     78179. H6WI070332008 30G     3/31/07
11 12/31/08      3449. H6WI070332008 YE      3/31/07
```

Comment: Seems like maybe I could just use an ifelse to test for NA? I voted up.

Comment: It produces `NA` if there is no `Q1`, which seems reasonable - what else should it do?

Answer (score 0):

see my comment above but something like this should work

```
   select(idfull, rep_typ, cov_end) %>%
filter(rep_typ == Q1) %>%
unique() %>%
select(-rep_typ) %>%
left_join(original_data, .)
```

Something like that?

Comment: i think i got the variable names wrong but the approach should work.